# Minimum number of charts in atlas

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Neither the sphere nor the torus admit an atlas with just one chart. Is there a way to know the minimum number of charts needed to cover a surface?

Comment: What is your definition of a chart?

Comment: Does the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097690/minimal-number-of-charts-covering-a-manifold?rq=1) answers your question?